# Can you echo php within php file

Tags: php

How can i print <?php to text within a php file ?

I have tried this

```
<xmp>
<?php
</xmp>
```

and this

```
echo '<?php';
```

all i want to show in the html is <?php   , i dont not want it closed anywhere

So the div on on the php page show  <?php

Comment: Did you check the source code of the file at the position where the text is supposed to show up? The `<` in `<?php` is probably seen as the start of an HTML element and thus doesn't show. Also, it's `<?php`, not `<?php;`

Comment: i made my question less confusing , i just want the text to show in html

Comment: You'll need to treat it like a string and encode it with htmlspecialchars() then.e.g. `echo htmlspecialchars('<?php');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Try to use function htmlspecialchars

```
echo htmlspecialchars("<?php");
```